# redis consuming way more memory than keys occupy

Tags: redis

Redis is taking way more space in memory than the keys itself:

```
$ top
> ... 74,2% memory (10gb)   2:17.61 redis-server
```

But the keys takes no more than 500MB total, I checked using "memory usage" on all keys and summed.

There is something I noticed while running "memory stats":

```
 1) "peak.allocated"
 2) (integer) 12556833800
 3) "total.allocated"
 4) (integer) 12141956128
 5) "startup.allocated"
 6) (integer) 803216
 7) "replication.backlog"
 8) (integer) 0
 9) "clients.slaves"
10) (integer) 0
11) "clients.normal"
12) (integer) 11537845808
13) "aof.buffer"
14) (integer) 0
15) "lua.caches"
16) (integer) 180552
17) "db.0"
18) 1) "overhead.hashtable.main"
    2) (integer) 474232
    3) "overhead.hashtable.expires"
    4) (integer) 115256
19) "overhead.total"
20) (integer) 11539419064
21) "keys.count"
22) (integer) 8579
23) "keys.bytes-per-key"
24) (integer) 1415217
25) "dataset.bytes"
26) (integer) 602537064
27) "dataset.percentage"
28) "4.9627666473388672"
29) "peak.percentage"
30) "96.695999145507812"
31) "allocator.allocated"
32) (integer) 12143577352
33) "allocator.active"
34) (integer) 12207005696
35) "allocator.resident"
36) (integer) 12250742784
37) "allocator-fragmentation.ratio"
38) "1.005223274230957"
39) "allocator-fragmentation.bytes"
40) (integer) 63428344
41) "allocator-rss.ratio"
42) "1.0035829544067383"
43) "allocator-rss.bytes"
44) (integer) 43737088
45) "rss-overhead.ratio"
46) "0.99665284156799316"
47) "rss-overhead.bytes"
48) (integer) -41005056
49) "fragmentation"
50) "1.0055875778198242"
51) "fragmentation.bytes"
52) (integer) 67843576
```

There is this `clients.normal` that is taking all that memory space. Any ideas on how to debug?

This keeps going until it crashes.

Answer (score 1):

```
1) "peak.allocated"
2) (integer) 12556833800
```

Because the peak allocated memory is about 10GB. Although you removed many keys, the memory is not return to operation system. Check [this](https://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization#memory-allocation) for detail.

In order to decrease the memory consumption, you can restart Redis server.

Comment: There no other way to release without restart?

Comment: AFAIK, there's no better way